# Non prorated calendar billing for stripe subscriptions?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Using the checkout via the stripe-php SDK I have a standard annual membership for my site that costs $100 per year. If I sign up 26 March 2024, it will auto renew on 26 March 2025 as expected.

I am required to change the billing schedule to **calendar** year so 1 Jan to 31 Dec.

I am aware that I can set the `billing_cycle_anchor` to 31 Jan 2025. However, this introduces `proration_behavior` which is either `always` or `none`.

**Always** - prorates, so if I sign up 26 March, it will charge me $77 and invoice me at the full rate on 31 January 2025.
**None** - price is $0 today and don't have to pay until 31 Jan 2025, so almost a whole year of inadvertent free membership.

```
$nextYear = date('Y') + 1;
$checkout_params = [
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => $prices->data[0]->id,
      'quantity' => 1,
    ],
   ],
   'mode' => 'subscription',
   'success_url' => $success_url . '?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
   'cancel_url' => $return_url,
   'customer_email' => $email,
   'subscription_data' => [
     'billing_cycle_anchor' => strtotime("{$nextYear}-01-01"),
     'proration_behaviour' => 'none',
   ]
];

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create($checkout_params);
```

### Desired Outcome

I do not wish to prorate, if someone signs up today (26 March) I want them to be billed $100 (the full cost of the annual subscription). Then again on the billing period. Is this possible in Stripe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `payment` mode checkout session to charge your customer for an ad-hoc $100 membership (remember to set [setup_future_usage](https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-setup_future_usage) to save the payment method used in this payment), and create a [subscription schedule](https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) to start the subscription on 1 Jan next year.

Comment: This ^ I would only add that you'll need to set the saved payment method as default, either on the Customer or on the Schedule, as Checkout payment mode doesn't do it.  https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method / https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-default_settings-default_payment_method

Comment: Genius thank you. This solved my problem. Set up two prices for each membership product, one one-off price and one recurring price. Customer gets charged the one-off price on sign up and new subscription is automatically set (via webhook) for 1 Jan of the following year using the recurring price.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this with just the one Checkout Session call.

- Use `subscription_data.trial_end` instead of `billing_cycle_anchor`
- Remove `proration_behavior`
- Add a one-time Price to your `line_items`, which has the same amount as your recurring one.

Result = the Session will bill for the one-time Price today, and will bill for the recurring Price on the `trial_end` date, no prorations.

```
$checkout_params = [
 'line_items' => [
  [
   'price' => $prices->data[0]->id,
   'quantity' => 1,
  ],
  [
   'price' => $one-time-price,
   'quantity' => 1,
  ],
 ],
 'mode' => 'subscription',
 'success_url' => $success_url . '?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
 'cancel_url' => $return_url,
 'customer_email' => $email,
 'subscription_data' => [
  'trial_end' => strtotime("{$nextYear}-01-01"),
 ]
];
```

Comment: This works as well and is a good workaround. However, it changes the Stripe checkout button to "Pay and start trial" and uses the word "Trial" a few other places on the checkout screen. For my use case I didn't want the user to see the word "Trial" at all (as it's not really a trial at all).